# Is iOS UIkit/Swift throttling bandwidth speeds when on cellular data?

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, swiftui, uikit

I have made a video player for HLS files in AVPlayer, here is my config I've been using

```
func preloadSegment(for url: URL) {
        guard players[url] == nil else {
            print("Player for URL is already preloaded.")
            return
        }
        
        print("Preloading \(url.absoluteString)")
        

        DispatchQueue.main.async {
            let assetOptions = [AVURLAssetPreferPreciseDurationAndTimingKey: false]
            let asset = AVURLAsset(url: url, options: assetOptions)
            
            // Initialize the AVPlayerItem with the asset
            let playerItem = AVPlayerItem(asset: asset)
            
            // Customize the AVPlayerItem settings
            playerItem.preferredPeakBitRate = 4_000_000 // Setting to 4 Mbps
            playerItem.preferredForwardBufferDuration = 5
            playerItem.canUseNetworkResourcesForLiveStreamingWhilePaused = true
            
            // Limiting the resolution can be beneficial for certain network conditions
            if #available(iOS 11.0, *) {
                playerItem.preferredMaximumResolution = CGSize(width: 720, height: 1280)
            }
            
            // Initialize the player with the playerItem
            let player = AVPlayer(playerItem: playerItem)
            player.automaticallyWaitsToMinimizeStalling = true
            player.usesExternalPlaybackWhileExternalScreenIsActive = false
            player.allowsExternalPlayback = false
            
            player.currentItem?.preferredMaximumResolutionForExpensiveNetworks = CGSize(width: 360, height: 640)

            self.players[url] = player
        }
    }
    
    func cleanup() {
        for observer in playerObservers {
            observer.player?.removeTimeObserver(observer.observerToken)
        }
        playerObservers.removeAll()
    }
    
    func configuredPlayerItem(for url: URL) -> AVPlayerItem {
        let assetOptions = [AVURLAssetPreferPreciseDurationAndTimingKey: false]
        let asset = AVURLAsset(url: url, options: assetOptions)
        let playerItem = AVPlayerItem(asset: asset)

        playerItem.preferredPeakBitRate = 4_000_000
        playerItem.preferredForwardBufferDuration = 5
        playerItem.canUseNetworkResourcesForLiveStreamingWhilePaused = true

        if #available(iOS 11.0, *) {
            playerItem.preferredMaximumResolution = CGSize(width: 1280, height: 720)
        }

        return playerItem
    }
```

When connected to wifi, this plays near perfect, no lag, no wait, immediately plays! When I switch to Cellular data, it starts stalling so much more.

This makes no sense to me, because I'm not throttling the network conditions in xcode, I also testing my Cellular download speeds vs my Wifi, and Cellular is around ~300Mbps, whilst wifi is ~150mpbs

I then tested further with trying to get download speed by downloading an mp4 file inside my app.

```
class SpeedTestViewController: UIViewController {

    private var startTime: TimeInterval?
    private var stopTime: TimeInterval?
    private var bytesReceived: Int64 = 0

    // Label to display download speed
    private let speedLabel: UILabel = {
        let label = UILabel()
        label.textAlignment = .center
        label.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        return label
    }()

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        view.backgroundColor = .white
        view.addSubview(speedLabel)

        NSLayoutConstraint.activate([
            speedLabel.centerXAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.centerXAnchor),
            speedLabel.centerYAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.centerYAnchor)
        ])

        testDownloadSpeed()
    }

    private func testDownloadSpeed() {
        guard let url = URL(string: "MP4 URL") else { return } // Replace with your file URL
        let request = URLRequest(url: url)

        startTime = Date().timeIntervalSince1970
        bytesReceived = 0
        stopTime = nil

        let configuration = URLSessionConfiguration.default
        let session = URLSession(configuration: configuration, delegate: self, delegateQueue: nil)
        let task = session.dataTask(with: request)
        task.resume()
    }

    private func calculateSpeed() {
        guard let startTime = startTime, let stopTime = stopTime else { return }
        let elapsed = stopTime - startTime

        // Speed in bytes per second
        let speed = Double(bytesReceived) / elapsed

        // Convert to megabits per second
        let speedMbps = speed * 8 / 1_000_000
        DispatchQueue.main.async {
            self.speedLabel.text = String(format: "Download speed: %.2f Mbps", speedMbps)
        }
    }
}

extension SpeedTestViewController: URLSessionDataDelegate {
    func urlSession(_ session: URLSession, dataTask: URLSessionDataTask, didReceive data: Data) {
        bytesReceived += Int64(data.count)
        stopTime = Date().timeIntervalSince1970

        if dataTask.countOfBytesExpectedToReceive > 0 {
            // If the size of the file is known, update progress here
            print("huh")
        }
    }

    func urlSession(_ session: URLSession, task: URLSessionTask, didCompleteWithError error: Error?) {
        calculateSpeed()
    }
}
```

And it was clear to me, that Wifi was over 100mbps, which seems consistent with the speed test, whilst Cellular download was ~13Mbps!!

How can an app throttle bandwidth so much? From 300mbps to 13?

I tried search for a property that prevents apple from throttling the app's cellular data bandwidth, but I couldn't find anything.

I've tried setting the max resolution for "expensive networks", but that doesn't help.

I figure the problem is not actually in AVPlayer, but rather how much bandwidth a user's allowed to expend from their cellular data.

**Another thing I tested**

Inside my app's *Build Settings,*
I enabled "Release" for Testability, and "*Debug*" in different testing scenarios, this didn't help.

I also played with `automaticallyWaitsToMinimizeStalling`

and

```
        playerItem.preferredPeakBitRate = 4_000_000
        playerItem.preferredForwardBufferDuration = 5
        playerItem.canUseNetworkResourcesForLiveStreamingWhilePaused = true
```

But to no avail.

Is there a way to not throttle bandwidth in my app for users? These videos are a few seconds, and most of the time under 1mb, so I'm confused as to why they're being throttled.

I'd appreciate any help, and let me know if I need to add some more of my code to this question.

Thank you.

Comment: I think you are comparing apples and oranges here. How do you test your speed? Are you downloading the same file outside your app, as you are inside it? There is a difference between testing the connection to your povider, and downloading a file from some other host.

Comment: I am downloading the same file, i've tested with curl as well on Cellular data (by connecting mac to my hotspot) and it works great

Comment: You should try with both `preferredPeakBitRate` and `preferredPeakBitRateForExpensiveNetworks` set to 0

Comment: Some unrelated hints: you should create only _one_ URLSession object and use it for several requests. Make sure you store a reference to it. You _can_ choose the view controller as owner, but better use a dedicated object. You are using a view controller as delegate. This has some consequences: as long as the session is not invalidated, it keeps a strong reference to the delegate, and thus a reference cycle. So, make sure you _explicitly invalidate_ the session in your view controller when it "shuts down". In your code, the view controller and the session will leak.